# Find viewbox so that all elements are visible

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg-DOM-element. It can have several children ranging from simple elements like a rectangle to more complicated ones like paths.

Is it possible to find a viewbox for the svg-element so that all elements are visible but they are not to small. Lets say the furthest distance to each side should be 25% of the svg-width.

My current idea would be to first find the min and max of the x and y values of all children and then calculate the viewport from those but this seems like a pretty tedious task (especially for elements like paths)

```
function findMinMax(element) {
  let min = {x: Math.Infinity, y: Math.Infinity};
  let max = {x: -Math.Infinity, y: -Math.Infinity};

  switch (oElement.tagName) {
    case "rect":
      min.x = rect.getAttribute("x");
      min.y = rect.getAttribute("y");
      max.x = rect.getAttribute("x") + rect.getAttribute("width");
      max.y = rect.getAttribute("y") + rect.getAttribute("height");
      break;
    case "polygon":
      //...
      break;
    case "polyline":
      //...
      break;
    case "line":
      //...
      break;
    case "circle":
      //...
      break;
    case "path":
      //...
      break;
  }

  [...element.children].forEach(c => {
    let o = findMinMax(c);
    if (o.min.x < min.x) min.x = o.min.x;
    if (o.min.y < min.y) min.y = o.min.y;
    if (o.max.x < max.x) max.x = o.max.x;
    if (o.max.y < max.y) max.y = o.max.y;
  });

  return {min, max};
}
```

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call [getBBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) on each element. All SVGLocatable elements support that method and all graphics elements derive from SVGLocatable.

If you put all the elements in a `<g>` container you can call getBBox on the `<g>` and the browser will do all the calculations for you. The `<svg>` element works too so you might not even need to create a container.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Robert said (I did this previously) if you want a full example - https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/NWqWEOw

For some reason, the code in the sandbox below keeps being unresponsive but it works well in codePen.

On double-click, the svg viewbox is changed to zoom is as much as possible using the b_box technique.

Demo:

```js
const svgDrawing = document.getElementById('drawing');
// console.log(svgDrawing.currentTranslate);
let viewbox = svgDrawing.viewBox.baseVal;
// console.log("viewbox", viewbox);
let original_w = viewbox.width;
let original_h = viewbox.height;
let w_h_ratio = 2;
const g = document.getElementById('437'); 
//console.log(g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);
// const extra = document.getElementById('example'); 
// console.log(extra.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix);
const b_box_br = document.getElementById('b_box_bottomRight');
const b_box_tl = document.getElementById('b_box_topLeft');
const b_box_max = {left: Infinity, top: Infinity, right: 0, bottom: 0};
var point = svgDrawing.createSVGPoint();

function zoomEvent(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (evt.deltaY > 1) {
    zoomInOut(-1, 10);
  } else {
    zoomInOut(+1, 10);
  }
}

function zoomInOut(direction, stepSize) {
  if (direction > 0) {
    viewbox.width -= w_h_ratio * stepSize;
    viewbox.height -= stepSize;
  } else {
    viewbox.width += w_h_ratio * stepSize;
    viewbox.height += stepSize;
  }
}

function zoomToSize(x, y, width, height) {
  viewbox.x = x;
  viewbox.y = y;
  viewbox.width = width;
  viewbox.height = height;
}

function zoomFull(evt){
  console.log('full')
  evt.preventDefault();
  viewbox.width = original_w;
  viewbox.height = original_h;
  console.log("Zoom 100%");
  const elements = [...svgDrawing.childNodes];
  console.log("elements", elements);
  var inside = true;
  for (let el of elements){            
    if (el.nodeName == "#text"){
      //this is not a real node
    } else if (el.id.includes('b_box_')){
      //these are just our guide nodes
    } else if (elementIsInside(el, svgDrawing)){
      inside = true;
    } else {
      inside = false;
    }
  }
  // var dir = inside ? +1 : -1;
  // zoomInOut(dir, (100/(10**i)));
  zoomToSize(b_box_max.left, b_box_max.top,
             b_box_max.width, b_box_max.height);
}

function elementIsInside(el, box){
  var result = false;
  el_rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  point.x = el_rect.right;
  point.y = el_rect.bottom;
  var invertedSVGMatrix = el.getScreenCTM().inverse();
  var p = point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);
  point.x = el_rect.left;
  point.y = el_rect.top;
  var p2 = point.matrixTransform(invertedSVGMatrix);
  let trans = el.transform.baseVal;
  if (trans.length > 0){
    const matrix = trans.consolidate().matrix;
    p.x += matrix.e;
    p.y += matrix.f;
    p2.x += matrix.e;
    p2.y += matrix.f;
  }
  if (p.x > b_box_max.right){
    b_box_br.setAttribute('cx', p.x);
    b_box_max.right = p.x;
  }
  if (p.y > b_box_max.bottom){
    b_box_br.setAttribute('cy', p.y);
    b_box_max.bottom = p.y;
  }
  b_box_br.setAttribute('r', 5); 
  
  if (p2.x < b_box_max.left){
    b_box_tl.setAttribute('cx', p2.x);
    b_box_max.left = p2.x;
  }
  if (p2.y < b_box_max.top){
    b_box_tl.setAttribute('cy', p2.y);
    b_box_max.top = p2.y;
  }
  b_box_tl.setAttribute('r', 5); 
  
  b_box_max.width = b_box_max.right - b_box_max.left;
  b_box_max.height = b_box_max.bottom - b_box_max.top;
  
  console.log(p2.x, p2.y, p.x, p.y);
  console.log(b_box_max.right,b_box_max.bottom);
  box_rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (el_rect.left >= box_rect.left &&
      el_rect.right <= box_rect.right &&
      el_rect.bottom <= box_rect.bottom &&
      el_rect.top >= box_rect.top){
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  // console.log("result_" + el.tagName, result)
  return result;
}

svgDrawing.addEventListener('wheel', e => zoomEvent(e));
svgDrawing.addEventListener('dblclick', e => zoomFull(e));

//resizeSVG();

window.onresize = function() {
  console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // console.log(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   resizeSVG();
};

function resizeSVG(){
  if ((window.innerWidth - 40) / w_h_ratio > (window.innerHeight - 120)){
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight - 120);
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("width", w_h_ratio * (window.innerHeight - 120));
  } else{
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("height", (window.innerWidth - 40) / w_h_ratio);
    svgDrawing.setAttribute("width", (window.innerWidth - 40));
  }
  viewbox = svgDrawing.viewBox.baseVal;
  original_w = viewbox.width;
  original_h = viewbox.height;
  w_h_ratio = 2;
}
```

```css
.preview{
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 0.8;
}
.graphic{
  stroke: #000055;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
.draggable{
  cursor: grab;
}
.selectionBox {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: none;
}
#content{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
svg{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Editor:</h1>
  <div id="content">
    <svg id="drawing"
         title="Layouteditor"
         viewBox="0 0 500 300"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         version="2.0"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      <g class="draggable preview" id="437" pointer-events="fill" transform="translate(150 50)">
      <rect fill="none" x="80" y="100" width="41" height="41"></rect>
      <line class="CDC300" fill="none" x1="140" y1="120" x2="121" y2="120" />
      <text class="CDC300" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="30px" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="131">T</text>
      <text class="CDC400" id="20010" text-anchor="end" x="75" y="125">=HTC1+HSP1</text>
      <circle class="insertpoint" cx="140" cy="120" r="3" />
      <circle class="pin" cx="140" cy="120" r="2" />      
    </g>
    <g id="a123" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
      <line class="hotwater graphic" id="g123" x1="100" y1="120" x2="200" y2="120"></line>
    </g>
    <g id="example" transform="translate(100, 200)">
      <rect id="extra_box" stroke="purple" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"/>
    </g>
    <circle id="b_box_topLeft" stroke="green" fill="green"/>
    <circle id="b_box_bottomRight" stroke="red" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```